# Cartoon where a boy summons a demon like creature

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

It was on Netflix a number of years ago, the intro is similar to the song sail by awolnation. The boy finds a book and summons this demon-esk creature. In the second season the demon ends up getting corrupted or something by shadow. It had the creatures name and he was either chained or banished or something but I can't seem to find it no matter how hard I search

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? What did the boy look like? What did the demon look like? What did the boy do with the demon? And can you tell us anything you remember about any other characters in the show? Did the boy have family, for example? Friends? Did he attend school?